# Series convergence Question ( TIFR GS $2010$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Question is :

[image]

What i have done so far is :

I see that $\frac{\pi}{n}\rightarrow 0$ and so should be the sequence $u_n=\sin (\frac{\pi}{n})$.

i.e., $u_n$ converges to $0$ and so $(b)$ is true.

I remember that

> $\sin \theta$ is same as $\theta$ for small angles

So, I Guess $\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})=\frac{\pi}{n}$ for large $n$

So, I guess $$\sum _{n -\text{large}}u_n=\sum _{n -\text{large}}\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})=\pi \sum _{n -\text{large}}\frac{1}{n}$$

But then $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent so should be the series $$\pi \sum _{n -\text{large}}\frac{1}{n}$$ i.e., $\sum u_n$ is divergent.

So, I wanted to conclude $(c)$ is true. But then for above question there is only one correct option.

So, If $c$ is true then both $(a),(d)$ should be false which is not possible according to question.

So, just with some sense I see that $(c)$ should be the only possibility for the correct option as this does not contradict anything while other would contradict.

So, $(c)$ should be false.. But, I am not sure how to see this.

please help me to see this in detail...

Thank you

Comment: there should be only one correct option... So, if series is divergent it can not be convergent and so it can not be absolutely convergent... but then both $a,d$ will be false and both will be correct options where as given question has only one correct option..

Comment: a and d are false

Comment: @Nirdonkey could you please explain a bit... I also got the same result but i am not sure.

Comment: "sinθ is same as θ for small angles" is true to some extent.

Comment: Yes. I see that but it is not very helpful

Comment: c is absolutely true.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I'm not sure what you're asking now. Are you not happy with your argument to prove that $(c)$ is true?

Comment: I am quite happy with my solution for $c$ but in that exam each question should have only one correct option.... So, If $c$ is true, this should mean $a,d$ are false.. right??

Comment: Yes, the question is ill posed.

Comment: If it is so.. I am happy :) :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Enjoy.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, can you consider converting the image to text and answering your own question since you have the answer to it?

Answer (score 0):

the first and last options are false because consider the series $\sum sin(\pi/n)$ and use comparison test with $\sum{1/n}$,the limit comparison test of ratio of terms is $\pi$ which is non zero and the harmonic series is divergent,so the series diverges,so the series is not convergent.Before applying comparison test notice that the series has positive terms.